# Pandas Read CSV generating encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get pandas to read my csv, but it appends the `=" "` to all of my data. How do I remove this?

This encoding seems to go way when I open it in excel and save it as a csv, and then apply the read_csv function.

[image]

Comment: please, can you share your import code.  And if possible, the source data.

Comment: Code and data should be included in the question as text, not as an image

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('/Users/achan/downloads/2.csv')